# UDP Communication not working outside of Visual Studio Debugger

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, udp, firewall

I have two separate c++ applications (running on Windows 10) that need to communicate with each other on multiple UDP ports.  Both applications are running on one machine so I am just using the localhost IP on both ends.  The first application is a robust control program that generates a lot of data that is sent out on these ports.  The second application is a basic server that is designed to receive and process all this message traffic and occasionally send commands back to the first application.

When running in Visual Studio everything works as expected however running from the command line or a bash script my server app receives all the data as expected, but I cannot sending data to the control app.

I have tried tweaking the Windows Defender and symantic settings with no luck.  Is it possible something else is blocking communication only in one direction?  And why does it work in the Visual Studio debugger but not when running the executables from the command line?

Comment: What sort of application is this? If it's a UWP app there is a limitation where apps have to have a manifest capability to access localhost (or indeed other network locations - but local is special). The VS debugger, in some cases, grants this by default because it's really, really, usefull in many scenarios.

There's docs on this over at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/apps/hh780593(v=win.10)

Comment: I'm experiencing the EXACT opposite with VS2019 16.2.0 (my app's UDP only works OUTSIDE the debugger.)  Did you ever find a cause/solution?  It might be applicable to my case as well.

Comment: I had a similar problem and it appeared I accidently did something stupid with the listening sockets, creating and disposing it every 25 ms. When debugging I got away with this, apparently the debugger made things a bit slower so the short lived socket was just able to receive the message. I noticed when debugging the receive loop which was exited before the entire message was processed. Without the debugger I was less lucky, the socket never managed to receive and process the message. Just maintaining the socket until te message was received fixed it.